# Is there an equivalent of the Spread Operator in TypeScript for use with Interfaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a JavaScript project and would like to use TypeScript as well. In one scenario it would be nice if I could reduce the amount of repetition in this interface:-

```
interface Question {
  settings: {
    label: string
    description: string
    hidden: boolean
    followUp: {
      label: string
      description: string
      hidden: boolean
    }
  }
}
```

If there were some kind of Spread Operator that would be great:

```
interface QuestionSettings {
  label: string
  description: string
  hidden: boolean
}

interface Question {
  settings: {
    ...QuestionSettings
    followUp: QuestionSettings
  }
}
```

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Comment: `interface FollowupQuestionSettings extends QuestionSettings { followUp: QuestionSettings }`…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
interface QuestionSettings {
   label: string;
   description: string;
   hidden: boolean;
}

interface Question {
  settings: QuestionSettings & {
     followUp: QuestionSettings;
  }
}
```